# Parse listbox values from an html form with apache commons

Tags: java, html, form-submit, apache-commons

I am trying to parse an HTML form with apache commons fileupload, all textbox values pass as normal, also the submitted file, but I can't parse the Listbox values. The code for the parsing is

```
 @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletFileUpload  upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(req);
            for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(items.get(i).getName());
                System.out.println(items.get(i).getFieldName());
                System.out.println(items.get(i).getString());
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Any guideline would be really usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your HTML form indicate that its a multipart form (i.e. enctype='multipart/form-data')

Before parsing, validate first if the request servlet containts a multipart form (i.e. execute the  isMultipartContent method).

It will also be extremely helpful if you will post the HTML page you are parsing and the error message of e2.printStackTrace() (if there's any).